# Vortices in a Superconductor: triangular lattice VS other geometries

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, vortex, superfluidity

Why do [vortices in a superconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrikosov_vortex) (i.e. magnetic flux-tubes) form triangular [lattices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313096/226902)? In one of the articles I found, I read that a square lattice would cause repulsion but a triangular lattice will cause attraction. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Closely related but for a superfluid: [Triangular lattice arrangement of vortices in a superfluid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94789/226902). Philosophically, the answer is the same (triangular lattice is energetically favourable because it's a better way of packing "round" things).

Comment: "one of the article I read was that a square lattice would cause repulsion but the triangular lattice will cause attraction" -> may you provide the precise reference? This may also be of interest: [Why are superfluid vortex lattices stable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/663790/226902) (the lattice realized in an experiment must also be stable, not only minimize free energy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vortex lines in a superconductor (or a neutral superfluid) form a regular crystal. Just like in a solid the precise arrangement depends on the interaction between the vortices, and is the one that minimizes the energy (or free energy) of the system.

The profile of a single vortex line and the interaction between them can be obtained from the Landau-Ginzburg theory. For two parallel vortices with the same circulation the  interaction is
$$
E_{int} = \frac{\Phi_0}{2\pi\lambda^2}K_0(r/\lambda)
$$
where $K_0$ is a modified Bessel function, $r$ is the separation, $\lambda$ is the penetration length, and $\Phi_0$ is the flux quantum. The is a repulsive force, which decays exponentially with distance.

It is now a straightforward exercise, first undertaken by [Abrikosov](https://inspirehep.net/literature/9138), to compare the energy of a square lattice and a triangular lattice. The result (as described in the paper) is that the triangular arrangement is favored.